# Getting the line number of a shell script error

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

When I run the script I get this error

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `text.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The problem is the script is about 450 lines and it's really hard to find exactly where it's talking about

It would be great if I could just get a line number like

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `text.txt' for reading (No such file or directory) at line ***
```

Or if I set -x then just

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `text.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
Terminated at line ***
```

Comment: This is basically the line that did it. PS4='File=$BASH_SOURCE: LineNo=$LINENO: ' bash -x  script 2>&1 | grep -B1 'awk: fatal:'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add line numbers to `bash -x` output:

```
PS4='$LINENO:' bash -x  script
```

For complex cases where scripts call one another, it can be handy to know not just the line number but also the file name:

```
PS4='$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' bash -x  script
```

`PS4` can be further customized as you please.  For example:

```
PS4='File=$BASH_SOURCE: LineNo=$LINENO: ' bash -x  script
```

#### Filtering the output

If we know what error message we are looking for, we can filter the output to get just that message and its corresponding file name and line number:

```
$ PS4='File=$BASH_SOURCE: LineNo=$LINENO: ' bash -x  script 2>&1 | grep -B1 'awk: fatal:'
File=script: LineNo=3: awk 1 text.txt
awk: fatal: cannot open file `text.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: It seems like when then happens the script just runs till the end of the file and so the line numbers are there, but I don't see how this is any different from just entering :set number in vim. I just want the line number of the error not of every command that's happening

Comment: @C.Monster If bash supported that behavior, that would be a nice thing.  It seems to me that  providing line numbers with error messages would be something it should do by default.  But, it doesn't.  I provided a partial work-around in the addition to the answer.